# Can't SSH into webserver to access Git repository

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, sshd, ssh-keys

I cleared registry files, uninstalled and reinstalled PuTTY, and checked my IP against a spambot database. I don't know what is going on behind the scenes, but in my troubleshooting I read that adding the `-v` tag gives more debug information, so I've done that and pasted the output here.

It should be noted that I do not have access to the physical Linux server that is hosting the Git repository, that is GoDaddy's modified cPanel (that for some reason, when a team member ssh-ed into the server does not allow for shutdown or sudo, which according to my research are the two commands that would be most helpful)

```
C:\Users\Fish's Ocean>ssh -v XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug1: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Fish's Ocean/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Fish's Ocean/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Fish's Ocean/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Fish's Ocean/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Fish's Ocean/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Fish's Ocean/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Fish's Ocean/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Fish's Ocean/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Credentials

Note that the `debug1: key_load_public` lines are incidental - they're not errors but just warnings that shouldn't affect the connection itself.

The most common reason for SSH issues to web hosts in my experience is that one hasn't set up an SSH/FTP identity. The username and password you use to connect will differ from any other Godaddy account credentials and often need to be set up explicitly - a process that is discussed in this [guide from Godaddy](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-my-web-hosting-account-with-ssh-secure-shell-4943). Be sure you're aware of your FTP credentials. As the guide reads:

> ### Find your FTP username and password
>
> 1. Log in to your GoDaddy account and open your product.
> 2. From the top menu bar, click Files & FTP, then select FTP Users.
> 3. To change your FTP username or password, click the Actions dropdown
>      and select Change Password or Change Username.
> 4. Fill out the necessary fields in the new window and
>      click OK to confirm the changes.
> 5. Use your FTP username and password to
>      establish the SSH connection...

Also note that commands like `sudo` or `shutdown` will only be available if you're using a VPS or Dedicated hosting from Godaddy. If you're on any kind of shared hosting, these won't be available to you.

### 2. Blacklisting

It's also not uncommon for web hosts like Godaddy to [blacklist IPs](https://ca.godaddy.com/community/Managed-WordPress-Hosting/GT-Metrix-Connection-Reset-By-The-Peer/td-p/114706) that have failed multiple connection attempts. Regardless of your initial problem, this may now be the reason for the connection being reset. You could chat with support again and see if it's possible for them to remove such a blacklisting. You could also try tethering your machine to your mobile device's internet connection(if possible) and have another shot using Putty.